# MySQL select most recent survey score per customer

Tags: mysql, view, inner-join

To put it very simply, I have a table that looks like this:

```
customer_surveys
----------------
id | customer_id | score | date
1  |           1 |     5 | 01-01-2013     
2  |           1 |     6 | 01-02-2013  
3  |           2 |     8 | 01-03-2013   
4  |           2 |     7 | 01-04-2013
```

I want to create a view that looks like this:

```
customer_survey_scores
----------------------
customer_id | score
1           | 6
2           | 7
```

The view simply selects the most recent survey score from each customer.

I was able to achieve this by writing a convoluted subquery, but need this to perform as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.customer_id, c.score
from customer_surveys c
inner join 
(
  select customer_id, max(date) as mdate
  from customer_surveys 
  group by customer_id
) x on x.customer_id = c.customer_id and x.mdate = c.date
```

Answer (score 0):

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) can be used for fetching ordered data within a group:

```
SELECT customer_id, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(score ORDER BY `date` DESC), 1) AS latest_score
FROM customer_surveys
GROUP BY customer_id
```

With the [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function you can get the first item of the delimited string.

Previous answer by @juergen-d will certainly work too.